# What to report for reliability analysis?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, reliability, reporting

After completing data collection on a reliability analysis where multiple examiners sampled each subject three times, which value should I report for descriptive statistics? If intra-rater reliability is much better than inter-rater reliability, should I report the intra-rater data for the descriptive statistics? One of the examiners is much more skilled and has more experience with the instrument than the other examiners.

Answer (score 1):

You can of course report both intra-rater and inter-rater reliability. Which one is more important in a given study depends on what point you are trying to make and what threat to measurement validity you are concerned about. If you want to show that ratings did not change over time and that the influence of contextual factors that different between measurement occasions, then intra-rater reliability will be important. If you want to show that ratings did not change across raters and that the influence of rater bias did not influence your measurements, then inter-rater reliability will be important.